# How to route to ashx or asmx in angular 2

Tags: javascript, web-services, angular, asmx

I have an app where I intend to host a generic handler and an ASMX service on the same domain as my angular 2 application.

I've followed some guides and have the routing to the components working correctly, but when I try and call the handler or the service from my angular services, it gets redirected back to the root of the site.

Is there a way to add a route without having to have a component for it?
Am I missing something here?